# $(this) when used inside function is pointing to window object

Tags: jquery, this

Problem: why $(this) inside setTimeout function points to window object and how can I get access of current div clicked inside setTimeout?

```
 <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">

      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

JS:

```
$("div.inner").on('click',function(e){

    //code block start
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
    var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
    console.log(relX);
    console.log(relY);
    //code block end

    setTimeout(function(){
        //inserting code block here to see my problem
    },200);

});
```

JSbin:http://jsbin.com/pumaxe/1/edit

Comment: The context is changed when it is used within setTimeout and setInterval. Set `this` to a variable and reference the variable.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for answer. I think the reason is setTimeout is method of Window object thats why 'this' keyword is pointing to window object. Right?

Comment: setTimeout being a function of window object is not the sole reason for it to execute with window as the context. That is thinking in traditional OOP terms. JS is different, functions in JS as first class citizens, they can exist without being bound to an object. You can bind them to an object using the Function.prototype.bind(), after that it will always run with that object as the `this` value. If you don't bind them to anything, it will have the `window` as the context by default. This is true even for functions you create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to cache the current element `this` and `e` in global variables before getting into the `setTimeout` as shown below.

Please bear in mind that `setTimeout` and `setInterval` run in the global scope; thus they only have access to global variables and functions ... see them as `window.setTimeout()` and `window.setInterval()`:

```
$("div.inner").on('click',function(e){
    window.that = $(this);
    window.e = e;  

    setTimeout(function(){
        //code block start
        var parentOffset = that.parent().offset(); 
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
        console.log(relX);
        console.log(relY);
        //code block end
    },200);

});
```

**UPDATE**

One could also use a closure as suggested by @Dom in the comments below. **A closure would not need global variables** (*and for that reason is a much better approach as we try our best not to clutter the global scope*) but we would have to pass to the closure the values we want to use in `setTimeout`:

```
$("div.inner").on('click',function(e){

    (function( that, e ) { //<<---- corresponding variables used within closure
        setTimeout(function(){
            //code block start
            var parentOffset = that.parent().offset(); 
            var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
            var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
            console.log(relX);
            console.log(relY);
            //code block end
        },200);
    })( $(this), e );  //<<---- values passed to closure from click handler

});
```

Comment: Someone is getting very downvote happy. Good answer +1. I suggest providing info on closures, just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways to do this, but probably the easiest is to use a second variable to hold a reference to div element.

```
$("div.inner").on('click',function(e){

//code block start
var div = $(this);
var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
console.log(relX);
console.log(relY);
//code block end

setTimeout(function(){
//inserting code block here to see my problem
// Now you can use the div variable in the outer context in here, without using this.
// Search google for JavaScript closures for more info on this.
},200);

});
```

Comment: Not sure why, your answer is correct. Perhaps downvoter ignored the comments you provided in the setTimeout?

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of Javascript function scope, take a look on this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Try this:

```
$("div.inner").on('click',function(e){

    var $that=$this;
    //code block start
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 

    setTimeout(function(){
        //Use $that instead of $this inside your functions

    },200);

}
```

Comment: This an my answer uses the same technique, someone down voted these without explaining. Please mention the reason when down voting so others may also learn.